# Efficient calculation of var-covar matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, statistics, data.table, panel-data

I'm looking for efficiency gains in calculating the (auto)covariance matrix from individual measurements over time `t` with `t, t-1`, etc..

In the data matrix, each row represents an individual and each column represents monthly measurements (the columns are in time order). Similar to the following data (although with some more co-variance).

```
# simulate data
set.seed(1)
periods <- 70L
ind <- 90000L
mat <- sapply(rep(ind, periods), rnorm)
```

Below is the (ugly) code I came up with to get the covariance matrix for measurements/ lagged measurements. It takes almost 4 seconds to run. I'm sure that by moving to `data.table`, thinking more and not relying on loops I could cut the time by a big amount. But since covariance matrices are ubiquitous I suspect there already exists a standard (and efficient) way to do this in R that I should know about first.

```
# Get variance covariance matrix for 0-5 lags    
n_lags <- 5L # Number of lags
vcov <- matrix(0, nrow = n_lags + 1L, ncol = n_lags + 1)
for (i in 0L:n_lags) {
  for (j in i:n_lags) {
    vcov[j + 1L, i + 1L] <- 
      sum(mat[, (1L + (j - i)):(periods - i)] *
          mat[, 1L:(periods - j)]) /
      (ind * (periods - j) - 1)
  }
}
round(vcov, 3)

       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,]  1.001  0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[2,]  0.000  1.001 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[3,]  0.000  0.000 1.001 0.000 0.000 0.000
[4,]  0.000  0.000 0.000 1.001 0.000 0.000
[5,] -0.001  0.000 0.000 0.000 1.001 0.000
[6,]  0.000 -0.001 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.001
```

Comment: Have a look at `cov()`

Comment: Thanks. But if you are suggesting `cov(mat)[1:6, 1:6]` than that's slightly different... since I am not looking for covariance of `t=1` with `t=2` but in general `t` with `t-1`... but maybe I can use that function if I setup my matrix differently (?).

Comment: check the `?ccf` function?

Comment: Perhaps `covmat <- cov(mat)` to get covariances between columns, then you can extract the figures for lag `L` with something like `diag(covmat[-(1:L),])`

Comment: @BenBolker `Error in ccf(mat) : univariate time series only`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar: That works... almost... but it requires some ugly corrections, since cov uses `ind -1` for each cov + in my case I know the mean to be zero but `cov` does calculate and subtract the mean.

Comment: Are you sure of your covariance formula? Seems like some centering is missing, right?

Comment: If you really care about performance, I think your best shot would be a single-pass Rcpp algorithm. The only problem I see with this R code is that it create a lot of matrices (copies).

Comment: @F.Privé, Centering: it is missing on purpose here... since in this case (and my real case) the true mean is known to be zero...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@F. Privé's `Rcpp` implementation is a good starting place, but we can do better. You will notice in the main algorithm supplied by the OP that there are many replicated fairly expensive calculations.  Observe:

```
OPalgo <- function(m, p, ind1, n) {
    vcov <- matrix(0, nrow = n + 1L, ncol = n + 1)
    for (i in 0L:n) {
        for (j in i:n) {
            ## lower and upper range for the first & second multiplicand
            print(paste(c((1L + (j - i)),":",(periods - i)," 
                          ",1L,":",(periods - j)), collapse = ""))

            vcov[j + 1L, i + 1L] <- 
                sum(mat[, (1L + (j - i)):(periods - i)] *
                                mat[, 1L:(periods - j)]) /
                                    (ind * (periods - j) - 1)
        }
    }
    vcov
}

OPalgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags)
[1] "1:70 1:70"  ## contains "1:65 1:65"
[1] "2:70 1:69"
[1] "3:70 1:68"
[1] "4:70 1:67"
[1] "5:70 1:66"
[1] "6:70 1:65"
[1] "1:69 1:69"  ## contains "1:65 1:65"
[1] "2:69 1:68"
[1] "3:69 1:67"
[1] "4:69 1:66"
[1] "5:69 1:65"
[1] "1:68 1:68"  ## contains "1:65 1:65"
[1] "2:68 1:67"
[1] "3:68 1:66"
[1] "4:68 1:65"
[1] "1:67 1:67"  ## contains "1:65 1:65"
[1] "2:67 1:66"
[1] "3:67 1:65"
[1] "1:66 1:66"  ## contains "1:65 1:65"
[1] "2:66 1:65"
[1] "1:65 1:65"
```

As you can see, the product `mat[,1:65] * mat[,1:65]` is performed 6 times above. The only difference between the first occurrence and the last occurrence is that the first occurrence has an additional 5 columns. So instead of computing:

```
sum(mat[ , 1:70] * mat[ , 1:70])
sum(mat[ , 1:69] * mat[ , 1:69])
sum(mat[ , 1:68] * mat[ , 1:68])
sum(mat[ , 1:67] * mat[ , 1:67])
sum(mat[ , 1:66] * mat[ , 1:66])
sum(mat[ , 1:65] * mat[ , 1:65])
```

We can compute `preCalc[1] <- sum(mat[ , 1:65] * mat[ , 1:65])` one time and use this in the other 5 calculations like so:

```
preCalc[1] + sum(mat[ , 66:70] * mat[ , 66:70])
preCalc[1] + sum(mat[ , 66:69] * mat[ , 66:69])
preCalc[1] + sum(mat[ , 66:68] * mat[ , 66:68])
preCalc[1] + sum(mat[ , 66:67] * mat[ , 66:67])
preCalc[1] + sum(mat[ , 66:66] * mat[ , 66:66])
```

In each of the above, we have reduce the number of multiplications by `90000 * 65 = 5,850,000` and the number of additions by `5,850,000 - 1 = 5,849,999` for a total of `11,699,999` arithmetic operations saved. The function below achieves this very thing.

```
fasterAlgo <- function(m, p, ind1, n) {
    vcov <- matrix(0, nrow = n + 1L, ncol = n + 1)
    preCals <- vapply(1:(n + 1L), function(x) sum(m[ , x:(p - n + x - 2L)] * 
                                               m[ , 1L:(p - n - 1L)]), 42.42)
    for (i in 0L:n) {
        for (j in i:n) {
            myNum <- preCals[1L + j - i] + sum(m[, (p - n + j - i):(p - i)] * m[, (p - n):(p - j)])
            vcov[j + 1L, i + 1L] <- myNum / (ind * (p - j) - 1)
        }
    }
    vcov
}

## outputs same results
all.equal(OPalgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags), fasterAlgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags))
[1] TRUE
```

Benchmarks:

```
## I commented out the print statements of the OPalgo before benchmarking
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP = OPalgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags),
               fasterBase = fasterAlgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags),
               RcppOrig = compute_vcov(mat, n_lags), times = 5)
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
          OP 2775.6110 2780.7207 2843.6012 2784.976 2899.7621 2976.9356     5   c
  fasterBase  863.3897  863.9681  865.5576  865.593  866.7962  868.0409     5  b 
    RcppOrig  160.1040  161.8922  162.0153  162.235  162.4756  163.3697     5 a
```

As you can see, with this modification we see at least a 3 fold improvement but the `Rcpp` is still much faster.  Let's implement the above concept in `Rcpp`.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix compute_vcov2(const NumericMatrix& mat, int n_lags) {

    NumericMatrix vcov(n_lags + 1, n_lags + 1);
    std::vector<double> preCalcs;
    preCalcs.reserve(n_lags + 1);
    double myCov;

    int i, j, k1, k2, l;
    int n = mat.nrow();
    int m = mat.ncol();

    for (i = 0; i <= n_lags; i++) {
        myCov = 0;
        for (k1 = i, k2 = 0; k2 < (m - n_lags - 1); k1++, k2++) {
            for (l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                myCov += mat(l, k1) * mat(l, k2); 
            }
        }
        preCalcs.push_back(myCov);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= n_lags; i++) {
        for (j = i; j <= n_lags; j++) {
            myCov = preCalcs[j - i];
            for (k1 = m - n_lags + j - i - 1, k2 = m - n_lags - 1; k2 < (m - j); k1++, k2++) {
                for (l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                    myCov += mat(l, k1) * mat(l, k2);
                }
            }
            myCov /= n * (m - j) - 1;
            vcov(i, j) = vcov(j, i) = myCov;
        }
    }

    return vcov;
}

## gives same results
all.equal(compute_vcov2(mat, n_lags), compute_vcov(mat, n_lags))
[1] TRUE
```

New benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(OP = OPalgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags),
               fasterBase = fasterAlgo(mat, periods, ind, n_lags),
               RcppOrig = compute_vcov(mat, n_lags), 
               RcppModified = compute_vcov2(mat, n_lags), times = 5)
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
          OP 2785.4789 2786.67683 2811.02528 2789.37719 2809.61270 2883.98073     5    d
  fasterBase  866.5601  868.25555  888.64418  869.31796  870.92308  968.16417     5   c 
    RcppOrig  160.3467  161.37992  162.74899  161.73009  164.38653  165.90174     5  b  
RcppModified   51.1641   51.67149   52.87447   52.56067   53.06273   55.91334     5 a
```

Now the enhanced `Rcpp` solution is around 3x faster the original `Rcpp` solution and around 50x faster than the original algorithm provided by the OP.

**Update**

We can do even better.  We can reverse the ranges of the indices i/j so as to continuously update `preCalcs`. This allows up to only compute the product of one new column every iteration.  This really comes into play as `n_lags` increases.  Observe:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix compute_vcov3(const NumericMatrix& mat, int n_lags) {

    NumericMatrix vcov(n_lags + 1, n_lags + 1);
    std::vector<double> preCalcs;
    preCalcs.reserve(n_lags + 1);

    int i, j, k1, k2, l;
    int n = mat.nrow();
    int m = mat.ncol();

    for (i = 0; i <= n_lags; i++) {
        preCalcs.push_back(0);
        for (k1 = i, k2 = 0; k2 < (m - n_lags); k1++, k2++) {
            for (l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                preCalcs[i] += mat(l, k1) * mat(l, k2); 
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = n_lags; i >= 0; i--) {  ## reverse range
        for (j = n_lags; j >= i; j--) {   ## reverse range
            vcov(i, j) = vcov(j, i) = preCalcs[j - i] / (n * (m - j) - 1);
            if (i > 0 && i > 0) {
                for (k1 = m - i, k2 = m - j; k2 <= (m - j); k1++, k2++) {
                    for (l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                        ## updating preCalcs vector
                        preCalcs[j - i] += mat(l, k1) * mat(l, k2);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return vcov;
}

all.equal(compute_vcov(mat, n_lags), compute_vcov3(mat, n_lags))
[1] TRUE
```

`Rcpp` benchmarks only:

```
n_lags <- 50L
microbenchmark(RcppOrig = compute_vcov(mat, n_lags),
                 RcppModified = compute_vcov2(mat, n_lags),
                 RcppExtreme = compute_vcov3(mat, n_lags), times = 5)
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
    RcppOrig 7035.7920 7069.7761 7083.4961 7070.3395 7119.028 7122.5446     5   c
RcppModified 3608.8986 3645.8585 3653.0029 3654.7209 3663.716 3691.8202     5  b 
 RcppExtreme  324.8252  330.7381  332.9657  333.5919  335.168  340.5054     5 a
```

The newest implementation is now over 20x faster than the original `Rcpp` version and well over 300x faster than the original algorithm when `n-lags` is large.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I had in mind when I said that it could be optimized further.

Comment: Any hints on how include or learn how to import C++ functions to your enviroment? I tried `Rcpp::sourceCpp` but got errors

Comment: @snoram Did you add `#include <Rcpp.h>` and `using namespace Rcpp;` on top of the cpp file, and replace the `#` comment symbol with `//`?

Answer (score 9):

Just translating your code in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;    

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix compute_vcov(const NumericMatrix& mat, int n_lags) {

  NumericMatrix vcov(n_lags + 1, n_lags + 1);
  double myCov;

  int i, j, k1, k2, l;
  int n = mat.nrow();
  int m = mat.ncol();

  for (i = 0; i <= n_lags; i++) {
    for (j = i; j <= n_lags; j++) {
      myCov = 0;
      for (k1 = j - i, k2 = 0; k2 < (m - j); k1++, k2++) {
        for (l = 0; l < n; l++) {
          myCov += mat(l, k1) * mat(l, k2); 
        }
      }
      myCov /= n * (m - j) - 1;
      vcov(i, j) = vcov(j, i) = myCov;
    }
  }

  return vcov;
}
```

This is at least 10 times as fast as the R algorithm.
Yet, I feel like it could be optimized further.